# Create image file from array

Tags: python, c, image, bitmap, tiff

Essentially my problem is just finding an easy way to create an image file from an array.

My problem is unparsing CUPS raster files into images. The CUPS RGB raster file  header is 1800 bytes. If I input the width and height I can read the raster array contained in the file correctly into Photoshop in Mac order, with interleaved 16 bit data 00RRGGBB. I have written a utility which extracts the width and height from the header.

I'd like to write another command-line utility which takes the width, height and file-name as inputs, truncates the first 1800 bytes off the raster file, and creates a Tiff or BMP or whatever is easiest to write image with the array that is contained in the rest - any well-known image format will do.

program should be C or Python, run under Mac, Linux.

Comment: Your input size is 32 bits, not 16... The [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) is well known, and you can write out its header straight away (with correct W, H, and line span values). Then copy your data, last line first, and in ABGR order. If your alpha is always 0, you could do with a 24-bit BMP but then you need to take line padding into account as well, which can be a hassle.

Comment: Oh wait-- you must mean each *component* is 16 bits wide. If so, do you want/need to preserve this? BMP is 8 bit/component only.

Comment: yes, each color is 16 bits. so 00RRGGBB is one 32 bit word. I have written a file parser which gets W and H, and then reads in the array word by word (actually line by line)  so my problem is writing it out as a file. I would strongly prefer doing it in 16 bits (no data loss) but it is not imperative. Files are around 80MB (CUPS raster spool bitmap for one page).

Comment: ouch. 4x16 bits =  8bytes/pixel

Answer (score 0):

For Python, [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is the tool for this task. Use the [putdata()](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) (search the link for putdata) method on image objects to put the pixels from a list into an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/)，which supports many image formats.You can use RasterIO(...) method for reading image data.